# Process substitution syntax. Forward/right bracket vs backward/left bracket

Tags: bash, process-substitution

[tldp](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) lists two syntaxes for process substitution.
`>(command_list)` and `<(command_list)`

What is the difference, if any?

Comment: The fact that tldp presents both forms without explaining the difference illustrates how bad a reference tldp is.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, a significant difference. See http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution

> Process substitution is supported on systems that support named pipes (FIFOs) or the /dev/fd method of naming open files. It takes the form of
>
> <(*list*)
>
> or
>
> >(*list*)
>
> The process *list* is run with its input or output connected to a FIFO or some file in /dev/fd. The name of this file is passed as an argument to the current command as the result of the expansion. **If the >(*list*) form is used, writing to the file will provide input for *list*. If the <(*list*) form is used, the file passed as an argument should be read to obtain the output of *list*.** Note that no space may appear between the < or > and the left parenthesis, otherwise the construct would be interpreted as a redirection.

Examples: `comm` requires input files to be sorted:

```
comm <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

Usage of `>(cmd)` is less frequent. I typically only use it with `tee` to send some output to various pipelines

```
seq 10 | tee >(rev > out1) >(tac > out2) >(shuf > out3)
```